# Parameter referencing in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

In my code below I'm trying to reference a parameter which I created for creating subnets\cidr block for EC2 instance.

I guess, since I created CFCidrVPC1 as string and the actual IP address is not a string.

Something I am missing here.

Can someone guide me here. The reason I'm trying to do this is reuse the code in the future. I also tried to use `Ref` function within `Fn::Cidr` funtion but that didn't work either. so replace it with cidr block.

The error I'm getting is `"Value of property SubnetId must be of type String"`.

Please find my full script:

```json
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "Creating template to deploy 3 ec2 instances in 3 different AZs",
  "Parameters": {
    "CFCidrVPC1": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "10.10.0.0/16"
    },
    "CFCidrVPC2": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "10.20.0.0/16"
    },
    "CFEC2Instancetype": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "t2.micro",
      "Description": " Only t2.micro is available in the free tier account hence no any other options"
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "VPC1": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": {
          "Ref": "CFCidrVPC1"
        },
        "EnableDnsHostnames": "False",
        "EnableDnsSupport": "False",
        "InstanceTenancy": "default"
      }
    },
    "VPC2": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": {
          "Ref": "CFCidrVPC2"
        },
        "EnableDnsHostnames": "False",
        "EnableDnsSupport": "False",
        "InstanceTenancy": "default"
      }
    },
    "CFsubnet1": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "Properties": {
        "AvailabilityZone": {
          "Fn::Select": [
            "0",
            {
              "Fn::GetAZs": ""
            }
          ]
        },
        "CidrBlock": {
          "Fn::Select": [
            "0",
            {
              "Fn::Cidr": [
                "10.10.0.0/16",
                "2",
                "8"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "CFCidrVPC1"
        }
      }
    },
    "CFsubnet2": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "Properties": {
        "AvailabilityZone": {
          "Fn::Select": [
            "0",
            {
              "Fn::GetAZs": ""
            }
          ]
        },
        "CidrBlock": {
          "Fn::Select": [
            "1",
            {
              "Fn::Cidr": [
                "10.10.0.0/16",
                "2",
                "8"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "CFCidrVPC1"
        }
      }
    },
    "CFsubnet3": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "Properties": {
        "AvailabilityZone": {
          "Fn::Select": [
            "0",
            {
              "Fn::GetAZs": ""
            }
          ]
        },
        "CidrBlock": {
          "Fn::Select": [
            "0",
            {
              "Fn::Cidr": [
                "10.20.0.0/16",
                "2",
                "8"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "CFCidrVPC2"
        }
      }
    },
    "CFsubnet4": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "Properties": {
        "AvailabilityZone": {
          "Fn::Select": [
            "0",
            {
              "Fn::GetAZs": ""
            }
          ]
        },
        "CidrBlock": {
          "Fn::Select": [
            "1",
            {
              "Fn::Cidr": [
                "10.10.0.0/16",
                "2",
                "8"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "CFCidrVPC2"
        }
      }
    },
    "FirstECSinVPC1AZ1": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties": {
        "AvailabilityZone": {
          "Fn::Select": [
            "0",
            {
              "Fn::GetAZs": ""
            }
          ]
        },
        "ImageId": "ami-005bdb005fb00e791",
        "InstanceType": {
          "Ref": "CFEC2Instancetype"
        },
        "SubnetId": {
          "ref": "CFsubnet1"
        }
      }
    },
    "FirstECSinVPC1AZ2": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties": {
        "AvailabilityZone": {
          "Fn::Select": [
            "1",
            {
              "Fn::GetAZs": ""
            }
          ]
        },
        "ImageId": "ami-005bdb005fb00e791",
        "InstanceType": {
          "Ref": "CFEC2Instancetype"
        },
        "SubnetId": {
          "ref": "CFsubnet2"
        }
      }
    },
    "FirstECSinVPC2AZ1": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties": {
        "AvailabilityZone": {
          "Fn::Select": [
            "0",
            {
              "Fn::GetAZs": ""
            }
          ]
        },
        "ImageId": "ami-005bdb005fb00e791",
        "InstanceType": {
          "Ref": "CFEC2Instancetype"
        },
        "SubnetId": {
          "ref": "CFsubnet3"
        }
      }
    },
    "FirstECSinVPC2AZ2": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties": {
        "AvailabilityZone": {
          "Fn::Select": [
            "1",
            {
              "Fn::GetAZs": ""
            }
          ]
        },
        "ImageId": "ami-005bdb005fb00e791",
        "InstanceType": {
          "Ref": "CFEC2Instancetype"
        },
        "SubnetId": {
          "ref": "CFsubnet4"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add Exact error you are facing?

Comment: "Value of property SubnetId must be of type String USer Initiated"

Comment: Is that your whole script? Are you trying to create an ec2 instances in there somewhere too?

Comment: Yes I am trying to create 2 VPCs and EC2 instances within that. That is not my complete script.

Comment: Now added full script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in cloudformation is case sensitive.

You have:

```
"SubnetId": {
   "ref": "CFsubnet2"
    }
```

Try:

```
"SubnetId": {
   "Ref": "CFsubnet2"
    }
```

For all occurrences .

Comment: But i original question still remains .. how do i create subnets using parameters

Comment: Not sure what you mean by using parameters. You're already creating them in your script

Comment: After rectifying the "ref" to Ref"  i am getting this error .  The CIDR '10.10.1.0/24' is invalid. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidSubnet.Range; Request ID: 388e4f81-4711-4cab-bd6c-3d0f9418bdce)

Comment: Is that subnet cidr range within the vpc cidr range?